# Is it possible to use a Stream to collect an Object into a hashmap, rather than casting?

Tags: java, casting, java-stream

I have a map `myMap` of type `<String, Object>` which looks like:

```
(
"header", "a string value"
"mapObject", {object which is always of type map<String, String>}
)
```

I basically want to pull out the value of "mapObject" into a `Map<String, String>`

Initially I just cast it to an ImmutableMap like so:

```
(ImmutableMap<String, String>) myMap.get("mapObject");
```

But am wondering if there is a way to do this by making use of Stream.

I've currently got:

```
myMap.entrySet()
   .stream()
   .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, entry -> (String) entry.getValue()));
```

But I'm getting the following exception:

`class com.google.common.collect.RegularImmutableMap cannot be cast to class java.lang.String`

Is there a way to do this or am I better just sticking with the cast?

Comment: A problem that I see is that your Map values are not all the same type, which begs the question, why is the myMap even a Map? Shouldn't it be represented as a Java class, with a String field and a `Map<String, String>` field?

Comment: The map is the returned value of an existing helper method which takes a "message" in string format, splits into into header and values, and returns it as a map with header being the first entry and then a map of key value pairs being the second entry. Unfortunately I can't change this behaviour so have to work with the current implementation.

Comment: Is the helper method a method that you've created? What format does the String come to you in? JSON? XML? Something else? Please provide the details, in your question if possible. And does this Map that you get have multiple entries or just 2?

Comment: You have to cast no matter what - as you want to use one of your objects in your `Map<String, Object>` as a more specialized type. This is unsafe and streams have no magic way of solving it. The reason you get your classcastexception is because you are actually trying to cast both your values in `myMap` to String, although the second is a `Map<String, String>`.

Comment: Thanks, that makes perfect sense - the cast is always necessary given what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution could look like this:

```
Optional<Map<String, String>> result = myMap.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .filter(entry -> "mapObject".equals(entry.getKey()))
    .map(entry -> (Map<String, String>) entry.getValue())
    .findFirst();
```

Your error message came from the cast of the second entry set (of type Map) to string here: `entry -> (String) entry.getValue()`

Update:

Like Holger stated the best solution nevertheless is `myMap.get("mapObject")`. The above solution is only to show how the problem could be solved using the Streams API.

Comment: This achieves exactly what I was after. I see the issue in my original attempt that caused my error message now - cheers! Also realise that the cast is always necessary, this method just allows me to do it all in one go, rather than getting the object from the map and then casting it.

Comment: @CGrant You are still getting the object from the map and then casting it, just in a contrived and less efficient manner, while wrapping it in an `Optional`…

Comment: This entirely unnecessary use of the Stream API replaces a simple and fast map lookup with a linear search through the map, without solving any problem.